# Finite group and cyclic cover

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose the ﬁnite group $N$ surjects to ﬁnite group
$F$. It is true that for any $G = N ⋊_α \mathbb{Z}$ there are inﬁnitely many covers of $G$ that are cyclic and
surject to $F$.

But is this statement true for finitely generated $N$ or even general group $N$? Is there an article about it ?

Comment: Perhaps you could define exactly what you mean by a cyclic cover. And what is $Z$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Z is the set of integer. Sorry.

Comment: @MaJoad Derek asked you two questions, and you only answered one. Please answer his first question.

Comment: @YCor OK. I will do it.